# relativeLayout positioning issue

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.hawssiv02.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ff2222"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ff2222"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Name"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="send"
            android:onClick="Button"
             android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            />



        <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my code indicates that the button should be below the editText in a relativeView but like you can see in the image below it's not working and it's like the edit text is considered in the start edge but i positioned it in the parent center
[image]

Comment: Where is the RelativeLayout? Appears to be a formatting issue here

Comment: post your full xml file.

Comment: Try without `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your EditText

Comment: i tried using alingParent for the editText and it works fine but it doesn't work for centerInParent and centerVertical and Horizontal

Comment: and there is the full xml file

Answer (score 0):

Put this in Button :

```
android:layout_below:"@+id/editText"
```